# Microsoft Teams API Response can't display Chinese/Japanese

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm working with Microsoft Teams API with HTTP requests.
When I use Graph Explorer to retrieve my channel messages, it works fine.
However, when I try to use another platform to send the HTTP request, it shows something like \u3042\u308a\u304c\u3068\u3046 instead of Chinese or Japanese.

I tried to use UTF8, UTF16, ASCII to encode the response, however, the problem still remains.

***UPDATED***

My Http request works fine in graph explorer and postman, see below images.
[image]
[image]

However, when I tried to get the request with REQBIN which is an online request system, the result is not encoded, see below.
[image]

When I use unity to run this request with UnityWebRequest, the response is also not encoded. My C# code is as below,

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("api_link");

www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + getUserToken.userToken);

www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: Could you please update your question with request and response? BTW you mentioned another platform, which platform [Fiddler, Postman] you are talking about, The API requires ChannelMessage.Read.Group* , ChannelMessage.Read.All, Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All permissions, Make sure you have these in your access token while calling it externally

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did include all the permissions in my access token, I believe the reason is because of some encoding issues.